# How to set name in redux form field component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm using redux form, I'm getting error like this. How to solve this ?

Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `Field`, but its value is `undefined`.

My code :

```
<Field component={(props) => {                   
    return (
        <DateTimePicker {...props.name} {...year} name="year" value={this.state.year} onChange={change.bind(this.state.year)} time={false} initialView={"decade"} format={"Y"}/>
    )
}}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the code for the case when name is `undefined`. Lets suppose you want to set a default value if the name is unidentified

```
<Field component={(props) => {                   
    return (
        <DateTimePicker {props.name !== undefined? ...props.name : "Default Text"} {...year} name="year" value={this.state.year} onChange={change.bind(this.state.year)} time={false} initialView={"decade"} format={"Y"}/>
    )
}}/>
```

Also, you should pass some value to the prop `name` if it is a mandatory field. Otherwise you can remove the mandatory characteristic of that prop.

Comment: But value is not going to action creator, If I click on the input field, then only data is going.

Comment: I could not get you. Can you please explain more

Comment: After selecting a date, If I click on submit, this field value is not submitting.

Comment: Are you getting the same error after changing your code as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Ok.. So your this problem got solved. Right? You are able to see a defualt name on your date picker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138184/discussion-between-sunil-t-c-and-richa-garg).